# Adding a header to an exported file sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, header

i'm trying to make a log file with sql, that contains a header, but i am getting this error : ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated , because of the semicolon, that my header should contains.

```
select 'User. Name;
        User. Number;
        User. Data;' from dual;
```

Kind regards,

Comment: do you need newlines in you string?

Comment: i am using spool to log an output to a file

Comment: The question was "do you need newlines?"... that is: do you need to print newlines in your spool file?

Answer (score 0):

run them in one line like this. If you want them in new line add `chr(10)` :

```
select 'User.Name;'||chr(10)||'user.Number;'||chr(10)||'User.Data;' from dual;
```

because oracle consider `;` as to execute the command

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write something in a spool file by SQLPlus, you can simply use [`PROMPT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQPUG/PROMPT.htm#SQPUG052):

```
PROMPT User. Name; User. Number; User. Data;
```

or, if you need to print 3 rows:

```
PROMPT User. Name;
PROMPT User. Number;
PROMPT User. Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `spool` and want header to your query please execute before query:

```
SET HEADING ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
```

`PAGESIZE` should be something big as this means after how many line header will be repeated.